# How to use ssh-agent for offering host specific keys from ~/.ssh/config file and manage the passphrases?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I configured different hosts and keys for them in ~/.ssh/config file. 
But, to manage the passphrases of different keys, I seek help from ssh-agent by adding the keys to it, via ssh-add command. Now when I ssh my hosts, the agent offers all the keys it has one-by-one.

I searched how to restrict this behavior of ssh-agent and, used

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

in the config file for all hosts.

I successfully restricted the ssh-agent from offering the keys it has, by doing so, but the ssh-agent is no more managing the pass-phrases and I have to enter pass-phrase every time I ssh.

Is there a way to render only the key for the specific host I am ssh - ing (reading from the ~/.ssh/config file) and manage the passphrase too?

Comment: What OS is your client running on?  I asked because, e.g., on Fedora GnomeKeyring (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) pretends to be ssh-agent and mucks things up...  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/771272 ,  It doesn't support Ed25519 or NIST ECDSA types.  In some cases, it's crashed when loading those types.     Also, did you specify `IdentityFile path/to/id_rsa` in your ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? I definately cannot confirm this on Debian 18.04 running KDE. Specifying both `IdentityFile` and `IdentitiesOnly yes`, and having the key loaded in ssh-agent with `ssh-add`, ssh'ing into a machine doesn't prompt for the key password.

It seems to me `IdentitiesOnly yes` doesn't rely on a running ssh-agent, but when there is one, it will happily use it for the password. It will not iterate over the passwords.

Answer (score 9):

The issue can be resolved by doing the following:

1. Edit your client's `~/.ssh/config` file such that the host entry has the following:

   ```
   Host fooName
       Hostname foo.name.tld
       User usrname
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fooName.pub
       IdentitiesOnly yes
   ```

   Note that the `IdentityFile` directive refers to the *public* key and not the private key file.
2. Add the relevant private key to ssh-agent using `ssh-add`. You should be prompted for a password at this time.

Comment: Is this an undocumented feature of `IdentityFile`??? I tried this and it works, but I can find it documented anywhere.

Comment: On Debian 18.04 with KDE, this emits the following error:
`@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/manuel/.ssh/id_test.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/home/user/.ssh/id_test.ed25519.pub": bad permissions`

Comment: After setting permissions to `600` (which there is no need for a public key), it says `Load key "/home/manuel/.ssh/id_test.ed25519.pub": invalid format`

Comment: @Multisync Are you adding the _private key_ to sshagent? The filename in your last comment ends with `.pub`

Comment: @chb No, I was adding the public key. This was explicitely stated in this answer we are commenting: "_Note that the IdentityFile directive refers to the public key and not the private key file._" I think this is wrong, the private key must be used.

Comment: Not quite, you need to add the PRIVATE key to your SSH agent (which may challenge you for a password to decrypt the key), and then in `~/.ssh/config` you specify the PUBLIC counterpart via `IdentityFile`. If you are not running ssh-agent, or have not added the key (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`) then SSH falls back to treating the identity file as a private key.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a **public** key via `IdentityFile` and if the private side is loaded in `ssh-agent` it will be used. Otherwise it will be treated as a private key, and likely generate an error about an unprotected private key file.

1. Ensure `ssh-agent` is running
2. Add your identity to the agent with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

   - Respond to password challenge, if prompted
3. Add your identity's **public** key to `~/ssh/config`, e.g.:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   # Public key, SSH will consult ssh-agent
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

### Why would you want to do this?

It is best practice to encrypt private keys but it is inconvenient to have to respond to a password challenge every time you use your key. `ssh-agent` provides a means to cache decrypted keys, so you only have to respond to the password challenge to decrypt them occasionally.

But this creates a new problem: some hosts limit how many authentication errors they'll tolerate before closing the connection. If your `ssh-agent` has a lot of keys then you may hit this problem, which manifests as "Too many authentication errors".

To avoid this you can specify `IdentityFile` for a given host, and only that identity will be used. This neatly avoids "Too many authentication errors", but now you have to respond to the password challenge every time the key is used, essentially bypassing `ssh-agent` and the convenient caching mechanism!

If you know the identity (private key) is present in `ssh-agent`, you can get `ssh` to use it by specifying the **public** portion of the key, which is sufficient to locate which private key you are referring to without accessing it directly.

You can add/modify/remove passwords from private keys using `ssh-keygen -p`.

### About `ssh-agent`

`ssh-agent` never provides the decrypted key to any process. Instead processes like `ssh` send the cryptographic challenge they've received to `ssh-agent`, which returns a challenge response. This keeps your private keys secure, but also allows `ssh-agent` to be tunnelled, so remote system can access your identities (so long as you remain connected). See `man ssh_config` and `ForwardAgent`.

### Troubleshooting

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": bad permissions
```

This implies that `ssh-agent` is not running, or does not have the associated identity loaded. Check which identities are loaded with `ssh-add -l`, e.g.:

```
# ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities
```

Load the **private** key of the identity with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`:

```
# ssh-add /Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Check:

```
# ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:2Mn+jr5imURFStSWVaDHXhhx+6cyXXBoNjOfPLy2thQ /Users/meermanr/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Try again.