# ssh/pageant -- specify which key to use

Tags: ssh, putty

Background -- I have `putty` and `pageant` on my desktop PC.  My `pageant` has three different keys in it for different sets of machines.  For machine set A, I `putty` into my bastion host, "allow agent forwarding", and `ssh` from the bastion host to other hosts using the same key stored in `pageant`.

Problem -- when I `ssh` from the bastion host to my other hosts, `ssh` will try the wrong key first before finding the right key.  The actual `ssh` command works, but it is generating a lot of spurious "Failed publickey" warnings, and I need to find a way to make that stop.

Question -- Can I tell `ssh` or `pageant` the order to provide keys?  If so, how?

Comment: there is not an answer to this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338853/how-to-use-ssh-agent-for-offering-host-specific-keys-from-ssh-config-file-and)

Comment: [this looks promising](https://superuser.com/questions/273037/using-the-identityfile-directive-in-ssh-config-when-agentforwarding-is-in-use#answer-273094)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495785/6633